# How to send the value of i in the element a[i]?

Tags: c#, selenium

Is there any way to send the value of `i` in the element of `a[]`?

```
for (var i = 0; i < find-1; i++)
{
     driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[2]")).Click();
}
```

Comment: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[" + i + "]")).Click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you might be looking for this

```
for (var i = 0; i < find-1; i++)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a[" + i + "]")).Click();
}
```

Comment: Mohit, i should be used as variable

Comment: Ohhh Yeah @Anand I fixed `i` :D